# Is there a continuous surjection from the reals to the continuous functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, metric-spaces, continuity, real-numbers

$\require{begingroup}\begingroup
\newcommand{\cut}{\setminus}
\newcommand{\Implies}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\If}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\Iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\x}{\times}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} \newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}} \newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}} \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}} \newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$
It is known that the set of real numbers has the same cardinality as the set of continuous $\R$ to $\R$ functions---and therefore a bijection exists between them. My question is whether a **continuous** bijection exists between them, or at least a continuous *surjection* from $\R$ to $C(\R)$, where $\R$ has the usual metric and $C(\R)$ has whatever metric works.

The reason this interests me is I have always felt that one of the reasons differential equations are hard to solve is because we don't have a big enough "vocabulary" to describe all of the functions in continuous function space. This is in contrast to the space of real numbers where we *do* have a robust method to express any real number to arbitrary precision: decimal notation. And historically, decimals have allowed us to solve many previously intractable problems like, say, computing cube roots---something the ancient Greeks could never do.

If a continuous surjection exists between real numbers and continuous functions, we could then use decimal notation to describe any continuous function to arbitrary precision, instead of being restricted to compositions of elementary functions or their extensions. We might even be able to express functional operations in terms of arithmetic operations. And maybe this could (but I'm only speculating) give us a way to solve difficult differential (or other functional) equations in much in the same way decimals allowed us to compute cube roots.

---

But I'm going out on a limb now. Even if such a surjection exists, I have no idea how much it would actually help in solving such problems. But I'm very curious about that, so if anyone has any additional insights, please tell!
$\endgroup$

Comment: Is this space of functions connected?  If not, then the answer is no.

Comment: Right. Consider the uniform topology on $C(\mathbb{R})$, for example. Is there any path connecting $x\mapsto 0$ and $x\mapsto x^2$ in $C(\mathbb{R})$ with the uniform topology? Under this topology, $C(\mathbb{R})$ is not path connected and is therefore not the continuous image of $\mathbb{R}$, which is path connected.

Comment: @MichaelLee How do you show that there is no path connecting $0$ and $x\mapsto x^2$?

Comment: @Michelle Yes it is vague, but I think I must leave it that way because any particular metric I name may not have the continuous surjection I'm looking for, but there may be a different metric that does. My question is whether there is *any* metric on $C(\mathbb R)$ that allows for a continuous surjection from $\mathbb R$ to $C(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @WB-man : of course there is such a metric, just not a nice one. You can even find a metric such that there exists an isometry between the two, but again the metric will look nasty

Comment: @haemi Consider $A = \{f\in C(\mathbb{R}) : \|f\|_{\infty} < \infty\}$ and $B = \{f\in C(\mathbb{R}) : \|f\|_{\infty} = \infty\}$. Both $A$ and $B$ are open, $A\cap B = \emptyset$, and $A\cup B =
C (\mathbb{R})$. $x\mapsto 0$ is in $A$, and $x\mapsto x^2$ is in $B$.

Comment: @MichaelLee Thanks! Very elegant and easy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there any metric on $C(\mathbb{R})$ that allows for a continuous surjection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $C(\mathbb{R})$.

Of course there is, for a boring reason. Let $F\colon C(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb R$ be any bijection (the sets have the same cardinality). Define a metric on $C(\mathbb{R})$ by $d(f,g) = |F(f) - F(g)|$. Then $F^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\to C(\mathbb{R})$ is not only a continuous surjection, but an *isometric bijection*.

Totally useless, of course.

Here is something of more interest. Suppose $(V, d)$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space with a metric $d$ that makes it a complete metric space. Then there is no continuous surjection from $\mathbb R$ onto $V$.

Indeed, if $f:\mathbb{R}\to V$ is such a surjection, then $V$ is $\sigma$-compact:
$$
V = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty K_n,\quad \text{where } K_n=f([-n,n])
$$
But a compact subset of $V$ has empty interior, since [every locally compact Hausdorff topological vector space is finite-dimensional](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/locally-compact-topological-vector-spaces/). So we have written $V$ as the union of countably many closed subsets with empty interior, contradicting the [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem).

In particular, the above applies to $C([0,1])$ with the uniform metric, or to $C(\mathbb R)$ with some natural metrics like 
$$
d(f,g)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-n}\frac{\|f-g\|_n}{1+\|f-g\|_n} \quad\text{where } 
\|f-g\|_n = \sup_{[-n,n]}|f-g|$$

Comment: The metric should rather be a norm, right ? Or at least it should be compatible with the vector-space structure

Comment: @Michelle Thanks for your answer, but can you explain more about why the trivial metric you define is "useless"? Is it because its notion of two functions being "close" is very different from our intuitive one?

Comment: @Max I think they meant to include the fact that it is also a topological vector space, since this is used later.

Comment: @WB-man You can define any metric you like on any space, but typically if we have preexisting structure on the space we would like the metric to have something to do with that structure.

Comment: @Max That's your added assumption, not OP's.

Comment: @Jason But would a stricture-respecting metric be necessary in order to establish a useful correspondence between real numbers and continuous functions (e.g. one that could help in solving differential equations)? I expect it may, but do we know then that no such structure-respecting metric exists?

Comment: @WB-man The metric given by Michelle's answer just uses a bijection $F:C(\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R$ to "pretend" that $C(\mathbb R)$ is really $\mathbb R$. This is possible with any bijection, and is not very interesting. You cannot hope to use such a metric in anything useful because it neglects everything we know about $C(\mathbb R)$ except its cardinality. How will the cardinality of $C(\mathbb R)$ help you in solving a differential equation?

Comment: @Jason Ah, I think I see now. And I think that answers my earlier question about whether this trivial metric resembles any sensible notion we have of two functions being "close". It does not (necessarily). But would it be fair to say, then, that there is no metric for $C(\mathbb R)$ aligning with our intuitions that *also* admits a continuous surjection from $\mathbb R$ to $C(\mathbb R)$? Because I imagine such a surjection would be valuable in differential equations since we could approximate an arbitrary continuous function with a decimal fraction.